# Update a column with a null or empty string value not running in pg-promise

Tags: pg-promise

The following code works fine as long as the entry is not blank. However, sometimes a user may want to delete a text entry, and therefore the cell should be replaced with an empty value (or null).

```
db.one(`UPDATE objectives 
    SET details = $1 
    WHERE id = $2 RETURNING project_id`, [details, id])
```

Comment: So use `oneOrNone` method instead of `one`. This is the very basics of `pg-promise` that's [documented from the very beginning](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#methods). Please read documentation before opening new questions here.

Comment: If the first comments was enough, you can make it into an answer yourself, or delete the question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When querying for data with pg-promise, use:

.one if you are expecting one row (as an object)
.any if you are expecting an arrow of row objects
.none if you are expecting nothing returned
.oneOrNone if you are expecting one row or no rows returned.

the solution was to use `db.oneOrNone instead of db.one`

More info can be found: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#methods